View does not exist in YugabyteDB concurrent DDL
I am running YugabyteDB 2.14.2.0 on a single node setup, using a database that had been created as COLOCATED. In that database there are tables defined WITH (COLOCATED = FALSE), and I have defined a database FUNCTION create_view_on_table_if_needed() that creates a view on one of those tables if it does not exist (using SELECT * FROM table), with that function taking as input the name of the view and the table to create it on.
In a test I am running, with the view view_x initially non-existent, I have 4 threads that are calling this function simultaneously with 'view_x' as passed in parameter for the view, with each thread starting a transaction, calling this function, then performing some actions with the view 'view_x', and finally committing. What I am observing is that only 1 thread succeeds, and the other 3 threads are getting an error that the view view_x does not exist. Later on I created a function, called wait_until_view_is_available(), which for a max number of retries (10) checks that the view passed in as parameter exists (using pg_sleep(10 sec) between each retry). I modified the code in each thread, so that immediately after calling create_view_on_table_if_needed(), the wait_until_view_is_available() function is called. I have confirmed that in 3 of the 4 threads the wait_until_view_is_available() function exhausts the max number of retries without finding the view.
I thought that DDL statements such as CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW in YugabyteDB are non-transactional (i.e., their effects are observable immediately and also outside the current transaction), as opposed to PostgreSQL where they are transactional just like every other SQL statement. Or is this no longer the case? What could we do to overcome this problem, without creating the view up front?
Your input is greatly appreciated.

There is work ongoing to have transactional DDL but for the moment what you describe can happen. I can reproduce it by running 10 CREATE VIEW + SELECT at the same time:
drop table demo cascade;
create table demo as select now();
\! bash -c 'for i in {1..10} ; do psql -c "create or replace view demoview as select $i from demo" -c "select * from demoview" & done'

The reason is that the catalog must be shared by all tablet servers but doing so synchronously would not be scalable. Metadata is cached on each server and the cache is forced to be refreshed immediately only when necessary. I guess this is why the effect is not visible immediately. Waiting 1 second should be ok because the catalog version is passed through heartbeats. This works with my example:
\! bash -c 'for i in {1..10} ; do psql -c "create or replace view demoview as select $i from demo" -c "select pg_sleep(1)" -c "select * from demoview" & done'

Let me tell a little more about the background of what your are seeing:
Because YugabyteDB is a distributed database, we store the catalog separately from the normal data. In both YugabyteDB and PostgreSQL the catalog is special and handled differently than the normal data. In PostgreSQL, the catalog is stored on the local node as regular tables and cached in the PostgreSQL buffer cache like normal data. In YugabyteDB, the catalog is stored on the master, whilst the normal data is stored on the tablet servers.
In both YugabyteDB and PostgreSQL, the catalog data in use is a local copy in the backend. Any change that concerns the local backend catcache and relcache, will need to make that known to the backend. In PostgreSQL, this is done using the cache invalidation dispatcher, where each of the changes results in a message in the SI queue that must be consumed by all backends. In YugabyteDB, object creation such the view you create is a message to the master. The master has to register this change and apply it, and after that is done, it will broadcast the change to all the tablet servers by indicating a catalog version upgrade. The tablet servers put this catalog version change in a shared memory segment, which is read by all backends on each tablet server, and will invalidate their local backend cache and refresh it.
This means that even if you have processes using the same YSQL server, the creation of an object will not be visible instantaneous, despite these seemingly sitting 'next to each other'. An object should be visible in ~ 2* tserver to master latency.
A view is a definition of an object, the number of columns does not matter, because a view contains only of metadata, it has no data. It causes the view definition to be rewritten to access to the underlying objects of the view in the rewrite phase of the execution.
In general, also for monolithic databases, it's best to avoid DDL in concurrent transactional situations.
